# Prove a hitting time is a.s. finite

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

> Consider a standard Brownian motion $Y_t$ and the stopping time $$T = \inf \{ t \geq 0: Y_t = -1 \}$$
>   Show that $P(T < \infty)=1$

I fix $t>0$, and I want to show that $T$ is a.s. bounded.

To this end, I compute, using the fact that $Y_t - N(0,t)$:

$$P( T < t)=P(Y_t > -1)= \int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} dx = \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} dx =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} dx +\frac{1}{2}$$.

In the last equality I used that the normal density is an even function. Taking the limit as $t \rightarrow + \infty$, I obtain $$P(T< \infty) \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Now I use a self-similarity argument: I fix a $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and note that for the BM to hit $-n$ starting at $0$ it has to hit $-1, -2 \ldots, -(n-1)$. Moreover, the probability of hitting $-1$ starting at $0$ (call it $\theta$) is larger than $\frac{1}{2}$ and **it is equal** to the probability of the BM to hit $-2$ starting at $-1$, and so on. So

$$ \frac{1}{2} \leq P(T_{-n} < \infty) =\theta^n $$

Therefore $\theta  \geq \frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and hence as $n$ goes to infinity I have $\theta \geq 1$, which implies $\theta =1$ since it's a probability measure.

All in all, $$P(T<\infty) = \theta =1$$

Comment: Why do you say $P(T<t)=P(Y_t>-1)$?

Comment: @kccu because if it starts at $0$ and hits $-1$ before time $t$, then the value of the brownian path at $t$ has to be greater than $-1$.

Comment: No, if it hits $-1$ before time $t$, then it can be anywhere at time $t$. However, if we know that it has not *yet* hit $-1$ by time $t$, then $Y_t>-1$. In other words, $T>t \Rightarrow Y_t>-1$, and moreover, $Y_s>-1$ for all $s \leq t$.

Comment: @kccu Uhm but brownian path is continuous and start at $0$...  graphically I can't understand how it could be "anywhere".

Using your hint, I have $P(T>t) = P(Y_t>-1)$. Then $P(T < t)= 1-P(Y_t >-1) \leq \frac{1}{2}$,

Comment: $T$ is defined to be the first time $Y_t$ hits $-1$. If $T<t$, then we know that the Brownian motion hits $-1$ at some time *before* $t$. After that, the Brownian motion can go anywhere.

Comment: Also, my comment does not imply $P(T>t)=P(Y_t>-1)$, but rather $P(T>t) \leq P(Y_t>-1)$.

Comment: @kccu Okay, now it's clearer, thanks. 

So, $P(T< t) = 1 - P(T>t) $, and hence $P(T < t) \geq \frac{1}{2}$, since $P(Y_t > -1) \geq \frac{1}{2}$, right?

Comment: Not quite. You have $P(T<t)=1-P(T>t) \geq 1-P(Y_t>-1)$, but $P(Y_t>-1) \geq \frac{1}{2}$, so we can't string these inequalities together.

Comment: By the strong Markov property of Brownian motion, $\{Y_t +1 : t \geq T\}$ is a Brownian motion started at $0$, independent of $\{Y_t : 1 \leq t \leq T\}$. This implies that for $t > T$, $Y_t+1$ is normally distributed with mean $0$, so $Y_t$ is symmetric about $-1$. Thus $P(T<t)=P(T<t,Y_t>-1)+P(T<t,Y_t<-1)$, and these two probabilities on the right are equal. Thus $P(T<t)=2P(T<t,Y_t<-1)$. Since $Y_t<-1$ implies $T<t$, the last equation becomes $P(T<t)=2P(Y_t<-1)$.

Comment: @kccu I didn't think about strong markov property! Unfortunately, we just know that $P(Y_t < -1) \leq \frac{1}{2}$, so from the last equality w just have $$P(T<t ) \leq 1$$. What am I missing to conclude $P(T < \infty) =1 $?

Comment: Could you be more precise, if possible?

Comment: My last comment was a follow-up explanation as to why $P(T<t) \neq P(Y_t >-1)$. I have not posted a solution because I am not sure how the proof goes. This may be covered in [Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) Chapter 7 but I haven't looked closely.

Comment: @kccu Okay, thanks for the explanation, really appreciated! Looking at the answer of this post I think that I could get the result. verything is done with $a >0$, what should change in my argument ? I can't figure it out,

Comment: @kccu Also, from $P(T<t)=2P(Y_t<-1)=2P(Y_1 < -\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ I can compute $$\int_{- \infty}^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-u^2/2} du \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$

Hence $P(T < \infty) = 2 \frac{1}{2} =1$.

Do you think is okay?

Comment: Yes, we can also use the reflection principle.

Comment: @Sesame but the reflection principle works fine with $a>0$, while here $a=-1$, so it seems to me that a different argument has been required

Comment: If $T_a = \inf\{t \geq 0, Y_t = a\}$ with $a >0$, then $P(T < t) = 2P(Y_t \geq a)$ Thanks to the reflection property. To conlude for $a \leq 0$, use the fact that $T_a$ and $T_{-a}$ have the same law by the symmetry of the BM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set a filtred space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0}, \mathbb{P})$. We have $B$ a BM issued from $0$, i.e $B_0 = 0$
We define the r.v.
\begin{equation}
 \tilde{T}(\omega) = \inf\{t \geq 0, B(t,\omega) = 1\} \quad \forall\omega \in \Omega
\end{equation}
We can easily check that $\tilde{T}$ is in fact a stopping time as it is the first hitting time of the continuous process $\mathcal{F}_t$-adpated $B$ in the closed subset $\{1\}$.

Let's work with the geometric Brownian motion defined as :
\begin{equation}
\forall t \geq 0, \quad M_t^\lambda = \exp\left(\lambda B_t - \frac12\lambda^2t\right)
\end{equation} 
We can easilty show that the process $M$ is a continuous $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingale and that the r.v. $\tilde{T}\wedge n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is still a stopping time (as the min of two stopping time is still a stopping time) and it is **bounded**.

Thanks to the Doob's optional stopping theorem, the process $M_{\tilde{T}\wedge n}$ is a martingale and we have:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_0\left[M_{\tilde{T}\wedge n}^\lambda\right] = \mathbb{E}_0\left[M_{0}^\lambda\right] = 1 \quad a.s.
\end{equation}
Now, we can rewrite the first term as:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_0\left[M_{\tilde{T}\wedge n}^\lambda\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[M_{\tilde{T}\wedge n}^\lambda 1_{\tilde{T} < +\infty}\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[M_{\tilde{T}\wedge n}^\lambda 1_{\tilde{T} =+\infty}\right] \tag{1}
\end{equation}
On the event $\{\tilde{T} < +\infty\}$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_{\tilde{T}\wedge n}= M_\tilde{T}$. 
On the event $\{\tilde{T} = +\infty\}$, we have that $B_t \leq 1$ for all $t\geq0$. If $\lambda>0$, then we have that:
\begin{equation}
\exp\left(\lambda B_{\tilde{T} \wedge n} - \frac12\lambda^2\tilde{T}\wedge n\right) = \exp\left(\lambda B_{n} - \frac12\lambda^2n\right) \to 0 \quad a.s.
\end{equation}

Note that we have 
\begin{equation}
\forall n \geq \mathbb{N}^*, \quad 0\leq M_{\tilde{T}\wedge n}^\lambda 1_{\tilde{T} < +\infty} \leq e^{\lambda}
\end{equation}
Using the Lebgues theorem, we can pass on the limit in $(1)$ (+using the continutiy) and end up with :

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[M_{\tilde{T}}^\lambda 1_{\tilde{T} < +\infty}\right] = e^{-\lambda}\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-\frac12\lambda^2\tilde{T}\right)1_{\tilde{T} < +\infty}\right]
\end{equation}
Now using a decreasing sequence $\lambda_n$ to $0$ and using Beppo-levi theorem, we have:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\tilde{T}< +\infty) = 1 \quad a.s.
\end{equation}

We know that $B_t = -Y_t$ is still a Brownian motion. Then $\tilde{T} = \inf\{t \geq 0, B_t = 1\} \sim {T} = \inf\{t \geq 0, Y_t = -1\}$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}({T}< +\infty) = 1 \quad a.s.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really like the idea of using a geometric BM. I have two questions:

On the event $\{ T= \infty \}$, it means that the brownian path hit $-1$ in infinite time, and hence I would say $Y_t \geq -1$.

Comment: I was trying at the beginning (see comments above) to compute $P(T< \infty)$ in a more explicit way, could you please tell me if my **last comment** is an alternative way to prove it?

Comment: Did I wrote something wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I'm still struggling with the same problem, I don't understand why at $T = \infty$ you have $Y_t \geq -1$

Comment: So $\{T = +\infty\}$ means that the first time of hitting -1 by the BM is "infinity". So this means $Y_t \leq -1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
But since $Y_t$ starts at $0$, it seems to me that $\{ T= \infty \}$ means that I'm always "above" the level $-1$. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah sorry I thought we had $Y_t = a < 0$. Can't we use the above with $\tilde{T} = \inf\{t \geq 0, B_t = 1\}$ where $B$ is a BM and notice that $T$ and $\tilde{T}$ have the same law as $Y_t \sim - B_t$. I know that the proof is far fetched just to show that the stopping time is finite ?

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: Uh  now yes, it's more clear ! Just a little check: your procedure is really useful I think, because I know that it's "easy" (since $a=1>0$) to prove that $\tilde{T}$ is an a.s. finite stopping time. Hence, **no matter** how I show $\tilde{T}$ it's an a.s. finite stopping time, by using your last argument I can conclude that also $T$ is a.s. finite.

Comment: Yes. Another way to show this, we can notice that the BM "sweeps" the real line by going through each point indefinitely. In fact, we can show even that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, $T_a = \inf \{t \geq 0, B_t = a\}$ is finite.